# URL Request variable has different encoding SharePoint 2010/2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint

In part of my code in a SharePoint 2010/2013 program, I do the following:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), "_blank");
```

Where the url has something like `?doc=äñǣ.tif` (to test unicode).

On the other side, I want to grab that `doc` variable from the request:

```
this.Request.QueryString["doc"];
```

In 2010, this correctly comes back as `%u00e4%u00f1%u01e3.tif`, which then can be parsed into `äñǣ.tif`.

However, in 2013, I get something totally different: `%u00c3%u00a4%u00c3%u00b1%u00c7%u00a3.tif` which parses into `Ã¤Ã±Ç£.tif` which is wrong.

Do I need to specify some kind of UTF encoding for `Htmlpage.Window.Navigate` for this to work properly? How? Is there some telltale sign that the 2013 `doc` variable is some totally different encoding?